# MultiplayerSynchronizer error in Godot4 when building spawn

Tags: synchronization, multiplayer, godot4

i have been making a multiplayer RPG game and i have implement a building grid place system. The problem is when i build sth from the client side i get an error

> get_node: Node not found: "World/PlayerBuildings/CampFire1/MultiplayerSynchronizer" (relative to "/root").
> process_simplify_path: Condition "node == nullptr" is true.

The game in othe hand still be ok and the building appears in both sides(Host-Client). Any solution ??

Comment: This is probably not enough information for any of us to help you... Try creating a minimal reproducing example